# What is x-nautilus-desktop:/// and why do I have it?

Tags: nautilus

I have a new bookmark in my nautilus I didn't make.

[image: My nautilus left panel]

It links to my desktop.

What is it and where did it came from?

Am I giving desktop access to someone?

Comment: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=334860 risen from the dead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right click on `x-nautilus-desktop:///`, then click `remove`.

You added unintentionally the Desktop to your Bookmarks.

No one has access to your Desktop.

It happens to me after pressing the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get to the Desktop and subsequently  pressing without intention the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> which adds the actual path to the Bookmarks in Nautilus.

Comment: Note for those unfamiliar with it: Strg here is what's usually called Ctrl.

Comment: Classic rage key combination when logging out of `ssh`

Comment: there is no ui (context menu or) for that bookmark stuff? just found out about it thanks