# mysterious file with 3 forward slashes suddenly appeared

Tags: 14.04, nautilus-actions

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04.5`.

A mysterious folder has appeared in my list of places. It's called

```
x-nautilus-desktop:///
```

Needless to say, it won't open and I can't delete it.

My system has become fairly unstable recently (locks up, reboots itself occasionally) and possibly that's related.

What is this folder?

Comment: check http://askubuntu.com/questions/738554/what-is-x-nautilus-desktop-and-why-do-i-have-it - comment by  @muru and the answer there

Comment: Well that was fast! Three minutes after posting my problem some kind person named Yaron replied with the answer. Right click on the name (as it appears in the left "Places" area)  and click "remove".